# Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: add-on, error

I just installed Lamplighter v1.2.4 on ExpressionEngine v2.5.5 and when I view the Accessory, I see the following error. Any ideas?

```
Severity: Warning
Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
Filename: core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code
Line Number: 144
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this might be because the cache folder isn't writable. Lamplighter checks the file time to determine the "last checked" value. If the file wasn't written correctly, it won't get a proper numeric value.

Comment: I have double-checked and the expressionengine/cache/lamplighter dir and containing files are writable by php.